# Change a pixel value

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image that I opened using `LoadImageM` and I get the pixel data using `Get2D` put I can't seem to find any built-in function to change a pixel value.
I've tried using multiple things from `Rectangle` to `CV_RGB` but with no successful results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider checking out the new version of the opencv library.

You import it with

```
import cv2
```

and it directly returns numpy arrays.

So for example if you do

```
image_array = cv2.imread('image.png')
```

then you can just access and change the pixels values by simply manipulating `image_array` :

```
image_array[0,0] = 100
```

sets the top left pixel to the value to 100.

Depending on your installation, you may already have the `cv2` bindings, so check if `import cv2` works.

Otherwise just install `opencv` and `numpy` and you are good to go.

Comment: Actually I already have cv2 because I use `import cv2.cv as cv` at the beginning of my code. So in your opinion it would be worth it to only use cv2 and not cv, is that correct? By the way I found a function in cv called `Set2D` that does exactly what I want. Which is pretty obvious considering the name of the other function was `Get2D`...

Comment: Yes that is correct! Working with numpy arrays is so much easier than working with the old API. You can use all of the scipy and numpy functions directly on your openCV structures without having to convert everything back and forth. It is much much better.